# location from to

Tags: http

I am trying to implement a map/direction based application using Google maps V3 API. So far I have been able to display the map and show directions for two locations selected.
the first one is my current location , the second one is the location of costumer (his/her information exist in my database).
All the markers are being displayed in the output properly.

Comment: don't worry people in stack will help you even your language, the important thing is that you're explained for us the problem , and that's what we need

Comment: @akira i hope so

Comment: any help ???? :/

Comment: is there something wrong in my description , why there is no answer until now .
any advice for editing my question to be more specific , i think i'm really explain the issue  .